# How to monitor changing elements with Watir?

Tags: watir

I'm testing a webpage which has a particular div that changes every minute or so and I'd like to run a test to make sure that it is in fact changing and not stuck. Ideally I'd like to run this in perpetuity (or at least for a long time). Is this something that can be accomplished with Watir? Is there a better tool for this job?

Here is an example of what is happening:

```
<div class="widgets ui-scrollview-view" style="overflow: hidden; left: -11475px; top: 0px; width: 12150px;">
    <div id="main1" class="some_class">
    <div id="main2" class="some_other_class">
</div>
```

The main2 div is the one being displayed...each time there is an update the new div id is incremented and the old div gets moved up (e.g. main3 is displayed, main2 gets moved up, and main1 no longer shows up in the html). So after a period of time it might look like:

```
<div class="widgets ui-scrollview-view" style="overflow: hidden; left: -1350px; top: 0px; width: 2025px;">
    <div id="main2" class="some_class">
    <div id="main3" class="some_other_class">
</div>
```

I'd like to make sure that there are new divs being generated after a reasonable period of time.

Comment: Your answers are going to be very general and non-specific unless you give us more details such as some sample HTML, and an idea of what about that div is changing.  Is it the contents of the div that change, or the attributes of the div?  etc.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and thanks for helping me out! I have updated the original question with some sample html

Comment: Given what you describe, there are a couple potential solutions, but they are made easier if you have a consistent way to identify the container div that holds the ones that will be changing. Can you add in that detail to the sample HTML you posted? If that's not possible is there some unique pattern to the ID's of the others which would be distinct from other divs on the page. (so you could get them via regular expression)  e.g. in your example, as long as 'main' appeared nowhere else in any other id value, then that could be used.

Comment: Ok, updated the HTML snippet with a sample div. The class does not change, but the style values may change on occasion.

Comment: Updated my answer to be a bit more specific to the sample HTML details you have provided.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an attribute like class that is changing. and you have some other attribute that can be used to identify the object, then you can use the [`.attribute_value` method](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir/2.0.4/Watir/Element#attribute_value-instance_method) to examine the attribute you are interested in and see what it is currently set to.

e.g. (edited to reflect changes to question )

```
browser.goto("PageYouWantToMonitor")
1000.times do |i|
  puts "sample Number #{i}"
  puts "First div ID is: #{browser.div(:class => 'widgets ui-scrollview-view').div(:index => 0).attribute_value('id')}"
  puts "Second div ID is: #{browser.div(:class => 'widgets ui-scrollview-view').div(:index => 1).attribute_value('id')}"
  sleep 30
end
```

simple example, although for a long test, writing out to some kind of logfile with a timestamp plus the value might be more useful.  Ruby has some very useful date/time libraries built in, as well as file IO, a bit of googling ought to find some basic tutorials on each of them.

Answer (score 0):

You could run the test as long as you want with Watir. Please note that I am not so sure that any browser could be run in perpetuity. :)

The question is, how do you know which div to check? Is there anything that stays the same? As usual, 2-3 examples of how the div changes would help.

For example:

```
<div id="change">one</div>
```

changes to

```
<div id="change">two</div>
```

and then to

```
<div id="change">three</div>
```

I would be trivial to check the div text with

```
browser.div(:id => "change").text
```